# Eclipse live file filter

Tags: eclipse, plugins, filter, navigator

In Eclipse I can add and apply filters in the navigator view. That is good for permanent filters but not good for a quick file search. Using the file search functionalty is good for complex cases but what if I only want to find all files with name conf*.txt? I don't want to open a search dialog, I want to use a live filter like in: [image: file live filter]

Is there a way or plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these plugins.

- [InstaSearch](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch#.U2zi3nKoJk9).
- [Resource Tagger](http://taggerplugin.sourceforge.net/).
- [Glance](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glance#.U2zls3KoJk8) - mostly suites your need.